# manim example_scenes.py won't run

Tags: python, cmd, manim

I am using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZltiKHFWmv8) video to download and install manim on Windows 10. Whenever I try to run this code, it fails.

```
python -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
```

cmd throws a big error at my face. It last line is :
Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

[image: The error image]

What could be the problem and how can I prevent and/or solve it.
Thanks

Comment: DLL load failed: maybe you missed a step in the video? You only give us a partial error message, but if the full error gives you a filename.dll, you could try to manually locate it. If it is present on your computer, you environment variables might be missing a path to this dll?

Answer (score 2):

@Riddhiman 36, the thing you seem to be missing is the parsing library. You can install it using the command `pip install argparse` or `pip3 install argparse`(depending on your python version). To prevent any further issues, you can use the following command in your local Manim repo directory:-
`python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

It is likely an issue with the installation of numpy, scipy or pycairo; try (re)installing those.

Comment: This would be better as a comment. Thanks!

Comment: I have manim downloaded now. But it is on Ubuntu and not on windows. Downloading on Linux appeared to be 10x easier

Comment: Indeed; on Windows it can be much harder to find the binaries & etc. Glad it worked out for you!