# wont run example_scenes.py in Manim

Tags: manim

I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZltiKHFWmv8&t=543s)video as a tutorial

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434009/manim-example-scenes-py-wont-run)  is a similar problem with no solid solution

particular error code: (ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.)
not sure what to refer to if the only problem is that the file cant be found. if that's what this means.

[screenshot of my command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azwRx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Run This Command in the Command Prompt

```
pip install numpy
```